# New to Redisson (Redis java client) type io.netty.util.concurrent.Future cannot be resolved

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I have started to integrate Redission, redis java client to a sample java app. Now as soon as I extend `Redisson`, I get a error close to the `package` definition.

> The type io.netty.util.concurrent.Future cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

What does this mean ?

Comment: It means you're missing the Netty libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the netty libraries from [here](http://netty.io/wiki/using-as-a-generic-library.html). And integrated the `all-in-one` jar file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the redisson-all.jar which has netty dependency included.